# screen sharing with twilio without extension

Tags: web, twilio, screensharing

In my web applicatio i need functionality to share screen in video call. i'm using twilio and 
my video call functionality is working fine. 
i have seen link from twilio to share screen. (https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/01/screen-sharing-twilio-video.html)
but i need to develop chrome extension for screen sharing in chrome. is there any way by which i can develop screen sharing without extension ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist and author of that blog post here.

As described in the blog post, to add screen sharing functionality to your video call in Chrome, you need to create and release an extension. How to build that extension is described in this blog post on [screen capture in Chrome](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/10/screen-capture-in-google-chrome.html).

This is the only way to do it right now.

However, the Chrome team are working on standardising their approach and releasing support for the `getDisplayMedia` API. This is [already supported by Microsoft's Edge browser](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/05/screen-capture-in-microsoft-edge.html). It works much the same as `getUserMedia`:

```
  navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia().then(returnedStream => {
    stream = returnedStream;
    document.getElementById('screen').srcObj = stream;
  })
```

Look out for this [coming to Chrome soon](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6744724455030784).

Comment: Chrome 70 now supports `getDisplayMedia()`. The feature is [under a flag](https://addpipe.com/blog/screen-capture-in-chrome-70-with-getdisplaymedia/) but should be widely available in 71 or 72.